# Unable to collect results HTML5 speech recognition API

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I am using the speech recognition API but I am unable to retrieve the results whenever it's done.

Here is the piece of code that I am using:

```
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    recognition.onresult = function(event) 
    { 
        console.log(event) 
    }
```

This outputs (in console):

```
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: false
    clipboardData: undefined
    currentTarget: SpeechRecognition
    defaultPrevented: false
    emma: null
    eventPhase: 0
    interpretation: null
    path: NodeList[0]
    resultIndex: 0
    results: SpeechRecognitionResultList
    returnValue: true
    srcElement: SpeechRecognition
    target: SpeechRecognition
    timeStamp: 1408325350996
    type: "result"
    __proto__: SpeechRecognitionEvent
```

I just can't wrap my head around it. How do I retrieve the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is in the `results` list in your returned event. You can find the sample code to access it here:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

```
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var interim_transcript = '';

    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      } else {
        interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
    }
    final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);
    final_span.innerHTML = linebreak(final_transcript);
    interim_span.innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);
  };
}
```